# MongoDB | Ошибка: zsh: illegal hardware instruction mongod | KALI NETHUNTER

Tags: mongodb, железо, zsh

**Устройство:**

```
Xiaomi Redmi Note 8T (4/64)
Android 13 (ROOT | MAGISK SU)
KALI NETHUNTER
```

Пытаюсь установить **mongodb:**

```
apt update -y ; apt upgrade -y
apt install mongodb
```

**Запускают:**

```
mongod
```

Вылетает такая **ошибка:**

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  mongod
```

Пытался скачивать версию под Ubunte с официального сайта mongodb .tar.gz выполня установку через файл, та же самая ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить, искал в интернете такую проблему, находил, но не помогало

А вот на термукс - все легко установилось
Но мне хотелось бы использовать только Kali Terminal (терминал от kali nethunter)

Comment: Можно ли как то из термукс перенести файлы? Или что то такое сделать, будет ли это работать? Или дело не в монгоДБ? А в zsh или что то типо того..?

Answer (score 0):

Качайте версию под ПК, на телефонах ARM, AArch64 (64-битный ARM), а на компьютерах x86, x86-64 (64-битный x86), компьютер не умеет запускать инструкции для другой архитектуры...